# MySQL: Find row number of one record and select -50+50 records using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

the MySQL version is 5.7.2x.

I do have a list of some 1000 records in a table. They are ordered by field `start_date`.
I would like to load 100 of these records to display as list in UI. But not the first 100 or so, but 50 records before and 50 records after a known id (e.g. record with `id` = 511).

Of course getting this done in one request would be perfect, I'd also go for a solution with 2 requests. E.g. one request to find out the row number id 511 would have in a select over all records, and then really selecting the records on a second request having the `LIMIT X, Y` set correctly.

What I am struggling with is to find out the position the item with id would have, so I can set `LIMIT` sensibly.

Best regards
Philipp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL 8.0, it should be possible to solve this with a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        t.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY start_date) rn_asc
    FROM mytable t
)
SELECT c2.*
FROM cte c1
INNER JOIN cte c2 ON c2.rn >= c1.rn - 50 AND c2.rn < c1.rn + 50
WHERE c1.id = 511
```

The CTE assigns a row number to each record, ordered by `start_date`. Then, the main query selects the record that has id `511`, and self-joins with the CTE to pull out records with a +/-50 row number.